# How to attach OnClickListener to stickyHeader in RecyclerView which is added via itemDecoration

Tags: android, onclicklistener, android-recyclerview

I am trying to implement stickyHeaders in RecyclerView. Each Header will have minimum two Views (TextView and ImageView) and I would like to listen to clicks on each View separately so that I can take them to different activities.

Tried recyclerview-stickyheaders library: http://eowise.github.io/recyclerview-stickyheaders/

While playing around with this library, figured out that this listens to whole header based OnItemTouchListener. Is there a way to listen to clicks on individual views?

Apart from that, I tried adding OnClickListeners directly in the BigramHeaderAdapter (Header Adapter in the sample of the library) as outlined below.

I would like to know if there is a way to achieve this. Please Help!

Header Layout (top_header.xml example):

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:clickable="true"
android:paddingStart="@dimen/item_padding"
android:paddingEnd="@dimen/item_padding">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="40dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:gravity="left|center_vertical"
        android:textAppearance="?android:textAppearanceMedium"
        android:background="?android:colorBackground"/>

    <View
        android:layout_width="0.0dip"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="1" />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:layout_width="30dp"
        android:layout_height="30dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"/>
</LinearLayout>

<ImageView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:src="?android:listDivider"
    android:scaleType="fitXY"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

Try 1: Implemented View.OnClickListener while creating ViewHolder inside BigramHeaderAdapter (Header Adapter)

```
public static class ViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder implements View.OnClickListener {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        mHeaderListener.onThread(v, getPosition());
    }

    public TextView title;
    public ImageView image;

    public ViewHolder(View itemView, HeaderViewHolderClicks listener) {
        super(itemView);

        title = (TextView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.title);

        image = (ImageView) itemView.findViewById(R.id.image);


        mHeaderListener = listener;
        title.setOnClickListener(this);
        itemView.setOnClickListener(this);
    }

    public interface HeaderViewHolderClicks {
        public void onThread(View view, int position);
    }
```

Try 2: Added OnClickListener in onBindViewHolder inside BigramHeaderAdapter which is header adapter.

```
@Override
public void onBindViewHolder(ViewHolder headerViewHolder, final int position) {
    headerViewHolder.title.setText(items.get(position).subSequence(0, 2));
    Log.v("binded", items.get(position).subSequence(0, 2).toString());
    headerViewHolder.title.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("BigramHeaderAdapter : ", "Click on Thread " + position);
        }
    });

    headerViewHolder.image.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("Image click", " Clicked on Image " + position);
        }
    });

    headerViewHolder.itemView.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Log.v("Image click", " Clicked on ItemView " + position);
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: so the above is code (1 and 2) are working with library or not.

Comment: @bharat Both tries didn't work with the library.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Its pretty late but still I managed to achieve the touch listener by changing the `SingleTapDetector` class present inside `StickyRecyclerHeadersTouchListener's`.

This is my layout for the sticky header which i am using

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:orientation="horizontal"
android:padding="2dp">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stickyheader"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:textSize="20px" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/stickyseemore"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:text="@string/seemore"
        android:textColor="@color/textPrimary"
        android:textSize="20px" />
```

Here is the code for Detecting the touch

```
private class SingleTapDetector extends GestureDetector.SimpleOnGestureListener {
@Override
public boolean onSingleTapUp(MotionEvent e) {
  int position = mDecor.findHeaderPositionUnder((int) e.getX(), (int) e.getY());
  boolean touch=false;
  if (position != -1) {
    View headerView = mDecor.getHeaderView(mRecyclerView, position);
    long headerId = getAdapter().getHeaderId(position);
    if (headerView instanceof RelativeLayout) {
      View nextChild = ((RelativeLayout)headerView).getChildAt(1);

      if(nextChild.getX()<e.getX()){
          touch=true;
      }
    }
    mOnHeaderClickListener.onHeaderClick(headerView, position, headerId,touch);
    mRecyclerView.playSoundEffect(SoundEffectConstants.CLICK);
    headerView.onTouchEvent(e);
    return true;
  }
  return false;
}

@Override
public boolean onDoubleTap(MotionEvent e) {
  return true;
}}
```

Here i am checking the headerView type. If its relative layout , then i am getting the child element inside it. Once i gets the child elements then, using the position of touch & the default position of my element , I am determining if it was touched anywhere nearer to that element.